# What does numeric notation preceding Sort options refer to?

Tags: linux, shell, sorting

I've looked through several sources in search of trying to find out what this particular numeric notation before the sort options means:

```
tr -cs 'a-zA-Z' '[\n*]' < $1 |
gawk    '
        {count[$1]++}
        {for (item in count) printf "%-15s%3s\n", item, count[item]}' |
        sort +1nr +0f -1 
        #     ^    ^   ^ The +1 +0 -1 options, 
        #i assume the rest is normal sorting options
```

I understand the array assignment, the looping, the translation call, but i do not understand what the numeric options for sort do, in this context.

Any help to shed light on the situation, would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're asking about options to the UNIX tool `sort` so tagging this with `gawk` instead of `sort` was an odd choice.

Comment: Well, basically it was in the Litterature that i had for Gawk, so i could not differentiate to wether it was a Gawk specific feature or if it was a POSIX specific thing, as it was

Comment: Sometimes examples for 1 command involve others. It has nothing to do with awk at all, neither gawk nor POSIX awk nor any other awk. In your command line `tr` is a command, `gawk` is a different command reading the output of `tr`, and `sort` is yet  3rd command reading the output of `gawk`. You're asking about options for the `sort` command. You could replace everything before the `sort` with a `cat` or `sed` or `grep` or anything else that produces the same output as the `tr | gawk` is producing and you'd have the same question - that's how you know it has nothing to do with `gawk` (or `tr`).

Comment: I see ; Well, that was a insightful answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `info sort`:

> On systems not conforming to POSIX 1003.1-2001, ‘sort’ supports a
>   traditional origin-zero syntax ‘+POS1 [-POS2]’ for specifying sort
>   keys. The traditional command ‘sort +A.X -B.Y’ is equivalent to ‘sort
>   -kompare A+1.X+1,B’ if Y is ‘0’ or absent, otherwise it is equivalent to ‘sort -k A+1.X+1,B+1.Y’.
>
> This traditional behavior can be controlled with the
>   ‘_POSIX2_VERSION’ environment variable (*note Standards
>   conformance::); it can also be enabled when ‘POSIXLY_CORRECT’ is not
>   set by using the traditional syntax with ‘-POS2’ present.

Comment: Can you provide an example with the above options? It did not work for me in both standard and `GNU` sort

Comment: I've extended my answer with the next paragraph of the info documentation. You may need to set the correct environment variable to get things to work properly.